# Portability of auto kind/type conversions in numerical operations in Fortran

Tags: type-conversion, fortran, precision

According to the Fortran standard, if the operands of a numeric operation have different data kind/types, then the resulting value has a kind/type determined by the operand with greater decimal precision. Before the operation is evaluated, the operand with the lower decimal precision is first converted to the higher-precision kind/type.

Now, the use of a high-precision data kind/type implies there is accuracy to a certain level of significant digits, but kind/type conversion does not seem to guarantee such things<sup>1</sup>. For this reason, I avoid mixing single- and double-precision reals.

But does this mean that automatic kind/type conversions should be avoided at all costs? For example, I would not hesitate to write `x = y**2` where both `x` and `y` are reals (of the same kind), but the exponent is an integer.

**Let us limit the scope of this question to the result of a single operation between two operands.** We are not considering the outcome of equations with operations between multiple values where other issues might creep in.

**Let us also assume we are using a portable type/kind system.** For example, in the code below `selected_real_kind` is used to define the kind assigned to double-precision real values.

Then, I have two questions regarding numerical expressions with type/kind conversions between two operands:

- **Is it "portable", in practice?** Can we expect the same result for an operation that uses automatic type/kind conversion from different compilers?
- **Is it "accurate" (and "portable") if the lower-precision operands are limited to integers or whole-number reals?** To make this clear, can we always assume that `0==0.0d0, 1==1.0d0, 2==2.0d0, ...` , for all compilers? And if so, then can we always assume that simple expressions such as `(1 - 0.1230d0) == (1.0d0 - 0.1230d0)` are true, and therefore the conversion is both accurate and portable?

To provide a simple example, would automatic conversion from an integer to a double-precision real like shown in the code below be accurate and/or portable?

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(p=15)
  print *, ((42 - 0.10_dp) == (42.0_dp - 0.10_dp))    
end program
```

I have tested with gfortran and ifort, using different operands and operations, but have yet to see anything to cause concern as long as I limit the conversions to integers or whole-number reals. Am I missing anything here, or just revealing my non-CS background?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>According to [these Intel Fortran docs](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/expressions-and-assignment-statements/expressions/numeric-expressions/data-type-of-numeric-expressions.html) (for example), integers converted to a real type have decimals filled with zeros. For the conversion of a single-precision real to higher-precision real, the additional decimal places are filled by first setting the low-order bits of the converted higher-precision operand to zero. So, for example, when a single-precision real operand with a non-zero fractional part (such as `1.2`) is converted to a double, the conversion does not automatically increase the accuracy of the value - for example, `1.2` does not become `1.2000000000000000d0` but instead becomes something like `1.200000047683758d0`. How much this actually matters probably depends on the application.</sub>

Comment: "numbers without a fractional decimal component can be exactly represented in binary" is not true, at least if by "binary" you mean radix-2 floating point. (Also, the standard doesn't require radix-2 floating point to be used and allows radix-2 floating point to have quite small magnitude integers not exactly representable.) What level of guarantee are you after? "Standard strictly requires", "you should be shocked if something else happens", "more likely than not"? Note also that expecting results to be exactly the same in general across compilers isn't supported by Fortran standards.

Comment: @francescalus Ha - I don't suppose I'd expect results to always be exactly the same in general, but the whole notion of writing portable code so that one can reach the level of "shocked if something else happens" seems to be the goal. To improve my example code, do you suggest `selected_real_kind` or just `kind(0.d0)`?

Comment: Integer values are exactly representable as floating point values provided the magnitude of the integer value is less than `2**p` where `p` is the precision of a floating point entity.  For example, for IEEE-754 binary32, `p = 24`.  If `iabs(i) < 2**p`, then conversion of `i` is exactly representable.  If `iabs(i) > 2**p`, the the conversion may be exact but depends on trailing bits in `i` being zero.

Comment: @evets That's a good point - thanks. That helps to build confidence that certain kinds of conversions are more-or-less trustworthy, even if there is no standard that requires a certain result.

Comment: Update: I took @ francescalus suggestion and changed the example code so that it uses `selected_real_kind` instead of `real64` from `iso_fortran_env`. Since this question discusses precision, this change makes sense.